# Ruby on Rails and mongoid. Relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have some question about RoR and MongoDB(use gem mongoid).
For example I have two collection-
users(fields: id, username, age) and messages(fields: id, message, user_to, user_from).
I need to relate this collections.
The model user-

```
....
has_many :messages
```

The model message-

```
....
belongs_to :to_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_to'
belongs_to :from_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_from'
```

Call in my view-

```
- @messages.each do |message|
  %tr
    %td    
      = message.message
    %td
      = message.to_user.username
    %td
      = message.from_user.username
```

But it not working. Please tell me how to relate it.
B.R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide `inverse relation`

```
belongs_to :to_user, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :recieved_messages
belongs_to :from_user, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :sent_messages
```

user.rb

```
has_many :recieved_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :to_user
has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :inverse_of => :from_user
```

And you don't need the `foreign_key`, `Mongoid` will take care of it

Comment: Thanks. But sorry, Mongoid not take care of it without foreign_key. I pointed foreign_key and this working well.